# get Blob information with Catalano Framework

Tags: android, image-processing, frameworks

I am developing an app to detect blobs or object in image.I want to extract blob image from main image with boundary box around blob. how can i? or how can i get width or height of blobs. my code:

```
     btn_process.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FastBitmap fb, Greench, Redch;
            imageView1.setImageURI(null);
            imageView1.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap asli = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            fb=new FastBitmap(asli);
            ExtractRGBChannel grayGreen=new ExtractRGBChannel(ExtractRGBChannel.Channel.G);
            ExtractRGBChannel grayRed=new ExtractRGBChannel(ExtractRGBChannel.Channel.R);
            Greench=grayGreen.Extract(fb);
            Redch=grayRed.Extract(fb);
            Subtract sub=new Subtract();
            sub.setOverlayImage(Greench);
            sub.applyInPlace(Redch);
            OtsuThreshold otst=new OtsuThreshold();
            otst.applyInPlace(Redch);

            BlobDetection blobDetect=new BlobDetection();
            ArrayList<Blob> blobs=blobDetect.ProcessImage(Redch);
            ExtractBlob eBlobs = new ExtractBlob(blobs);
            Redch = eBlobs.Extract(blobDetect.getIdBiggestBlob(), Redch); 
                            // by this i am reach the biggest blob but with height and width of main image. but i need crop blob image in blob size.



            imageView1.setImageURI(null);
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(Redch.toBitmap());



        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered in Code Project too. I do this in desktop version, you can adapt in android. I'll do a sample in both enviroment in next version (1.3).

```
FastBitmap image = new FastBitmap("c:\\files\\blob.png");
image.toGrayscale();

Threshold t = new Threshold();
t.applyInPlace(image);

BlobDetection bd = new BlobDetection();
ArrayList<Blob> blobs = bd.ProcessImage(image);

image.toRGB();
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.red);

for (Blob blob : blobs) {
    ArrayList<IntPoint> lst = PointsCloud.GetBoundingRectangle(blob.getPoints());

    int height = Math.abs(lst.get(0).x - lst.get(1).x);
    int width = Math.abs(lst.get(0).y - lst.get(1).y);

    g.drawRect(lst.get(0).y, lst.get(0).x, width, height);
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, image.toIcon());
```